Why isn't my wine cooler powering on?
I recently saw a wine cooler on Kijiji for free. New, it costs $1700. I figured I'd pick it up and try fixing it. Right now, it does not start up at all when plugged in. The displays are unlit, no motor hum, no fan movement - dead. Pressing the power button gives no response. My guess is that there is a fuse blown somewhere. However I am not sure where the power supply control board would be. The receptacle it's plugged into is fine, and there is no damage to the cord or cord end.
When I picked it up, the guy said it needs a start capacitor. From what I've read though, a completely dead unit means a breaker or fuse and not a broken capacitor. One capacitor can be seen on the left side of the unit (white cylinder in the background). It is 8uf +/- 5% and 250V. I think it might be a run capacitor but I'm not sure. It seems to be in fine shape. No discolouration or burn marks are to be seen. I think the start capacitor is clipped onto the condenser, but again I'm not sure.
My biggest question is: where might I find the fuses in this machine? In Youtube videos I've been watching they pull off a panel, but I have already pulled the cage off and there are no more visible panels. Are they in that bundle of wires behind that plastic cage on the left side? Or - do you think I have this wrong entirely, and another part might be the culprit? Thanks in advance. Edit I uploaded a photo of the circuit diagram.
One page technical description
Manual online



Usually best to google make and model, to find manuals.  Cords/cables might have wires broken inside the insulation.  Broken wire works the same as a blown fuse, but might be wiggle enough to work.

What you need is the schematic diagram, found in a service manual, though some appliances have a copy taped inside (if you're lucky). Then you need someone with experience in repair, who would know what the schematic means, and how to test if component values are as expected.

The only fuse marked on that diagram is the one for the motor, labelled TK. The parts marked JK and CR appear to be the start and run capacitors. There aren't on any of the circuit boards, so they are either in the wires leading to the motor (for the fuse) or attached to the motor (for the capacitors).
The schematic doesn't give values for any of these; you would have to look at the existing part, or contact the manufacturer, to determine what replacements to get.
Note that this device has not passed US safety inspection; it just has a US plug on it. Up to you to decide how much to worry about that.

Your model is WC38SSDZBC as printed on the label.
Look online for manual/schematics.
Meanwhile fix the problem with blocked (kinked) drain line (bluish hose on upper-left side of image).
UPDATE
The PCB power board is under the black cover, where the two yellow wires go in.
Unclip the clip and remove the cover.
Unplug the power for your safety and inspect for fuse.
From the schematic provided there is a fuse to protect the compressor motor.
Possible cause for the fuse blowing is the failed start up capacitor.

Thanks! I updated the post to include an image of the circuit diagram and a link to the manual.

@cam2323 see my updated answer, let me know if it worked

Yes I was able to find the fuse! Then based on the dimensions I was able to order a replacement fuse and start capacitor. The dimensions matched exactly for both parts, and the rating on the capacitor was the same. Now just waiting for the part to show up, then I'll pop it in and see if that was the issue.

@cam2323 if you had a multimeter you could check the fuse and capacitor. Unfortunately we might have not fixed the actual problem. Something made the fuse blow. What kind of fuse was it ? If the capacitor stoped working, the motor would draw more current and blow the fuse, lets wait and see. In any case come back and report for others with simular problem.
